# Firebase docs reference unknown module

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine

Firebase has this piece of information here at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations:

> Client-side location selection for callable functions Regarding the callable function, client callable setups should follow the same guidelines as HTTP functions. The client can also specify a region, and must do so if the function runs in any region other than us-central1.
>    To set regions on the client, specify the desired region at
>   initialization:
>
> ```
> var functions = firebase.app().functions('us-central1');
> ```

I've been trying to find which node module `firebase` is referring to but I have had no luck.
I know that it is not `'firebase-admin' or 'firebase-functions'` but thats about it.
Anyone have any ideas what this might be referring to?

Edit:
I have now also tried using this with the imports `require('firebase')` and `require('firebase/app')` (as suggested) but neither of those seem to work. I also tried generating the app with `const app = firebase.initializeApp({});` and then running `app.functions("region")` or `app().functions("region")` but i keep receiving TypeErrors saying functions is not a function and app is not a function respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`firebase.app().functions('us-central1');` is a part of the firebase-js-sdk. [With source code documented on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/7866e2235998de53458c11a063c0fc588d982ae1/packages/functions/index.ts)

NPM component is @firebase/functions, that is [documented on the npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/functions).

However, it is not intended for standalone usage, and should be used along with [package Firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase).
You can install it using:

> $ npm i firebase

Comment: I tried using this with the imports ```require('firebase')``` and ```require('firebase/app')``` but neither of those seem to work. I also tried generating the app with ```const app = firebase.initializeApp({});``` and then running ```app.functions("region")``` or ```app().functions("region")``` but i keep receiving TypeErrors saying functions is not a function and app is not a function respectively.

Comment: Please try to follow this procedure to [initialize your app properly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) especially with proper config.
If it does not work, please post minimum reproducible code and full error descriptions in your question, or accept this answer and open new question for it.